# How do I print the calling method name

Tags: java

I want to be able to print the calling method name and not the method that contains the print method.  Is there a way to do this?

```
private void printOrderNumber() {
    String methodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
    System.out.println(methodName);


    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("variableOutput.txt", true)));
        out.println(methodName);
        out.println(var1);
        out.println("");
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //oh noes!
    }

}

private void order1(){

printOrderNumber();

}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'parent method' in Java. Do you mean 'calling method'?

Comment: Thread getStackTrace is the only way I know of.  Not particularly efficient.

Comment: As the method is private, i.e. completely under the control of the guy writing the class, i.e. you, why not just pass the calling method name as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through the stacktrace

```
import java.lang.*;

public class StackTraceElementDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      function1();
   }

   public static void function1()
   {
      new StackTraceElementDemo().function2();
   }

   public void function2() 
   {
      int i;
      System.out.println("method name : ");

      // print stack trace
      for( i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[i].
         getMethodName());
      }
   }
}
```

### **Edit:**

*This part is wrong:*

Second way would be to use `class.getDeclaredMethods()`:

```
for (Method method : Name.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    String name = method.getName();
}
```

Comment: Second way is wrong. 'getDeclaredMethods()' cant possibly help with finding the calling method.

Comment: I swear I tied .getStackTrace[2] and it didnt work.  Does now.  Thanks!